# print new string first character is the middle character of original string

Tags: python, string

For a string (three characters and more) that you have created please create a new string that follows the next rules:

- The first character of the new string is the middle character of the original string.
- The middle character of the new string is the last character of the original string.
- The last character of the new string is the first character of the original string.

Example:

- For odd length case, length of 9 characters:
  Let’s assume that the middle character is 9/2 rounded down that’s means that it is 4.
  “afffbeeec” –> “bfffceeea”
- For even length case, length of 8 characters:
  The middle character is also 4 because 8/2 equals 4.
  “axxxbyyc” -> “bxxxcyya”

Print your new string in the following way, for even length example:
`The rotated string is bxxxcyya`

this question was made me mad man i cannot planing the solve solution of that
need help

Comment: It will be easier if you provide enough example and specify your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast your string into a list, then it's easy

```
a="afffbeeec"
b=list(a)
mid=len(b)//2
b[0], b[mid]=b[mid], b[0]
b[-1], b[mid]=b[mid], b[-1]
print(''.join(b))
>>> bfffceeea
```